# can't find repo in sources.list

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I'm trying to remove "https://packagecloud.io/AllToMP3/alltomp3/ubuntu eoan Release" but I can't find it in sources.list I even did ppa purge etc

```
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/AllToMP3/alltomp3/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I also noticed this

```
404  Not Found [IP: 2600:1f1c:2e5:6900:c58b:7de3:e6d1:b7e5 443]
```

Comment: What ppa-purge command did you use? What is the output of `grep "packagecloud.io/AllToMP3/" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Comment: no I used "sudo ppa-purge https://packagecloud.io/AllToMP3/alltomp3/ubuntu eoan Release" but when I run grep some stuff

Comment: Please add the output of that in the question by [edit]ing.

Comment: too long by 89 characters

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CR0tHced

Comment: The repository information is in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/AllToMP3_alltomp3.list`. You can either comment the line or just delete the file followed by `sudo apt update`.